# Why system reminds me of runtime error that load of address 0x602000000018 with insufficient space for an object

Tags: c, data-structures, binary-tree, traversal

It is the NO.105 of leetcode.
The description of subject:
Given preorder and inorder traversal of a tree, construct the binary tree.

System reminds me of errors in this line:

```
"return bulid(node->left,preorderRemain,preorderSize,inorderLeft,inorderLeftSize);"
```

The code:

```
/**
 * Definition for a binary tree node.
 * struct TreeNode {
 *     int val;
 *     struct TreeNode *left;
 *     struct TreeNode *right;
 * };
 */


struct TreeNode* buildTree(int* preorder, int preorderSize, int* inorder, int inorderSize){
    struct TreeNode* root = NULL;
    struct TreeNode* bulid(struct TreeNode* node,int* preorder,int preorderSize,int* inorder,int inorderSize);
    return bulid(root,preorder,preorderSize,inorder,inorderSize);

}

struct TreeNode* bulid(struct TreeNode* node,int* preorder,int preorderSize,int* inorder,int inorderSize){
    node = malloc(sizeof(struct TreeNode*));

    node->val = preorder[0];
    if(preorderSize == 0) return node;

    int* inorderLeft;
    int* inorderRight;
    int* preorderRemain;
    int inorderLeftSize;
    int inorderRightSize;

    for(int i = 0;i<inorderSize;i++){
        if(inorder[i] == preorder[0]){

            inorderLeftSize = i;
            inorderRightSize = inorderSize - i - 1;
            inorderLeft = malloc(sizeof(int)*inorderLeftSize);
            inorderRight = malloc(sizeof(int)*inorderRightSize);
            preorderRemain = malloc(sizeof(int)*(preorderSize-1));

            for(int j = 0;j<i;j++) inorderLeft[j] = inorder[j];
            for(int k =i+1,t=0;k<inorderSize;k++,t++) inorderRight[t] = inorder[k];
            for(int p = 0,q=1;q<preorderSize;p++,q++) preorderRemain[p] = preorder[q];
        }   
    }
    preorderSize--;

    return bulid(node->left,preorderRemain,preorderSize,inorderLeft,inorderLeftSize);
    return bulid(node->right,preorderRemain,preorderSize,inorderRight,inorderRightSize);
}
```

The error:

```
Line 46: Char 12: runtime error: load of address 0x602000000018 with insufficient space for an object of type 'struct TreeNode *' (solution.c)
0x602000000018: note: pointer points here
 be be be be  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  02 00 00 00 ff ff ff 02
```

Comment: `Recursively*iteratively` allocating the memory but not freeing anywhere, eventually system will go out of memory at somepoint. That is what it is complaining.

Comment: when asking a question about a run time problem, as this question is doing, always post a [mcve] so we can reproduce the problem and help you debug it.